# Json decode converts to List<dyamic> instead of Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter

I am getting this response from the API:

```dart
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "company_id": 2,
        "surname": "Surname",
        "name": "Name",
        "employee_position_id": 1,
        "phone_number": "+xxx xxx xxx xxx",
        "email": "mail@mail.mail",
        "user_id": 1,
        "contact_level": null,
        "created_at": "2020-10-03T16:50:59.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-03T17:05:54.000000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "full_name": "Surname Name",
        "position_name": "IT",
        "company_name": "Company One"
    }
]
```

According to every tutorial I found, this code should work:

```dart
void _getContacts() async {
    var res = await Network().getData('/contacts');
    final Map<String, dynamic> body = json.decode(res.body);
    // print(body.runtimeType);
  }
```

However, it gives me this error:

```
E/flutter (23716): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

When I print the `body.runtimeType` it says `List<dynamic>`

I double checked, i tripple checked everything, json seems to be in a correct format, all the code seems to be written correctly.

How is it possible it gives me `List` instead of a `Map`? and how do I force the json.decode to give me a Map instead of a List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is List you have to iterate it.
if there is only one object of your list then you can use it like this

```
void _getContacts() async {
    var res = await Network().getData('/contacts');
    var response= json.decode(res.body);
    final Map<String, dynamic> body = response[0];
    // print(body.runtimeType);
  }
```

if there is more than one object on your list then you can use it like this

```
void _getContacts() async {
    var res = await Network().getData('/contacts');
    var response= json.decode(res.body);
    final Map<String, dynamic> body = response.map((e)=>e);
    // print(body.runtimeType);
  }
```

Comment: thank you, it's a step forward for me, however next error came right after `E/flutter (23716): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'` what now?

Comment: better to make a model class of it using https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ link and there is `fromJson` method which converts the JSON to your model class

Comment: Not sir, Abhi @narrei